# Library Dependency

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2015, static-libraries, libcurl

I'm making a **C++ based library** with Visual Studio 2015. I have my work based on **curl-7.51.0**, **OpenSSL-1.0.2j**, and **ZLib-1.2.8**. 


When I was using curl library (which was statically linked with openssl and zlib) I wasn't needed to add Include/Library paths of openssl and zlib (except for compiling). But when I use my library, Visual Studio gets the LNK1104 error that he can't find the libcurl_a.lib. 


Why does this happen? how can I statically/fully include curl library in my custom library?

Comment: Please add a Visual Studio 2015 tag indicating that your question is specific to that

Comment: @adam10603 Thank you for your advice.^^